# how to create a different colored compound path in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have created many shapes with different colors when i tried to convert it into a compound path all the path converted into a single color.

How can I do that with compound path or some other tool?

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot or something and why do you want to convert it to compound path?

Comment: are you looking to group the thing.

Comment: No Actually I want to give a single gradient to all my paths @joojaa

Comment: Actually I want to give a single gradient to all my paths@Rishab

Comment: @ChenthuranChen then just apply the gradient to selection anw use gradient tool to set the gradient. There is no need to combine anything when you do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. A compound path is treated as one single path, that's the whole point of a a compound path.

Any fill, stroke, effect or anything applied to your compound path is applied to the whole compound path, not just one sub path.

If you want to color part of your compound path differently you will need to duplicate the parts you want to color as new paths... But then you may as well not bother converting it to a compound path in the first place.

Comment: Yeah Actually your point is right. But If i want to use a single gradient to all my shapes. what would be the solution?

Comment: If you want to use a single gradient across all the shapes then a compound path is what you want

Comment: actually I want the shapes to be in different colors and i want a fade out effect among those shapes using single gradient with 0% opacity on the left and 100% opacity on the right. The non faded shapes should be in different colors. @cai

Comment: If I understand you correctly the best way would be to color your shapes separately and group them, then duplicate the group and convert the duplicate to compound path and set the transparent gradient to that